# How to detect if image is landscape from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the following code to check but it doesn't work.. always returns portrait even on images taken in landscape

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    //dismiss imagepicker controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    fishingSpotChosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (fishingSpotChosenImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    } else if (fishingSpotChosenImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || fishingSpotChosenImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        NSLog(@"landscape");
    }
  }
```

Im assuming it doesn't work because the image is actually in portrait when selected so how do I detect when the image has black bars like the following image..[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, in this case your "landscape" image orientation is still "UP" since the image is right-side up.

If you only care about images that are of the camera's 4:3 or 3:4 rectangular aspect ratio, perhaps you can just compare the image width to the image height to see whether it's wider than it is tall or vice versa using `UIImage`'s size property, ex.

```
if (fishingSpotChosenImage.size.height > fishingSpotChosenImage.size.width) {
    NSLog(@"portrait");
} else {
    NSLog(@"landscape");
}
```

Comment: So obvious yet didn't think about it. Thank you!